# Laravel5 route, Different in the blade template depending on routing

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

Depending on the routing that follows the address, it will display differently on the screen.

if /register ->

1. http://laravel.dev/register

   - resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php

`<nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-info fixed-top navbar-info' color-on-scroll='500'>`

else if /home ->

2. http://laravel.dev/home

   - resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php

`<nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-info fixed-top navbar-transparent' color-on-scroll='500'>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    @if(request()->is('register'))
        <nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-info fixed-top navbar-info' color-on-scroll='500'>
    @elseif(request()->is('home'))
        <nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-info fixed-top navbar-transparent' color-on-scroll='500'>
    @endif
```

Comment: thank you. Can I ask you one more question? One question I have asked is, if register or login, how do I write an if statement? Is there anything other than 
`@if (request()->is('register') or request()->is('login')`

Comment: You can use any other expression inside `@if()` instead of `request()->is('register')`. For example `@if(true) <div>This is true</div>  @endif`. Read more https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand it well. Does it work on the blade template? Can you show me the code? Thank you.

Comment: yes it works on blade template. What you didn't understand? How `@if ` statement works in blade template?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is using a **route parameter** of some kind as a flag to tell your page which "context" it's loading in.

For example, depending on how your routes are setup, you could add code either in the route function or controller function like:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = $url['path'];
$isRegisterPage = in_array("register", explode("/", $path));
```

Then you can check in your blade template for the variable "$isRegisterPage" to determine which NavBar to load.